# Download openstreetmap data filtered by specific changeset comment

Tags: openstreetmap, features, josm

From openstreetmap, I want to download only the features that have specific change set comments (like #ABC). I already know how to download OSM data (using JOSM) and found [this webpage](http://resultmaps.neis-one.org/osm-changesets?#2/33.9/1.4) shows filtered result only; no download option available (my required format) . 
It would be a great help for a newbie if anyone provides solution.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with your request is that it requires a lot of changeset data to be available and processed to find the ones matching your query. This is an unusual request (that would usually be done on a local copy of the data if needed), most live/public APIs focus on the current data of OSM not the changesets.

There is a service called "planet stream" that you can use to filter "diffs" and get the changeset/data desired. A diff is the data (and changesets) that have changed since the previous diff, in this case it's minutely diffs. You could build a system to collect the ones matching your query and record them over time.

- Blog post about Planet Stream, with example https://developmentseed.org/blog/2015/09/28/whats-trending-osm/
- Documentation of the Planet Stream API https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Augmented_Diffs
- Code of Planet Stream https://github.com/developmentseed/planet-stream